# How to put a label side by a progress bar with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, label, progress-bar

I want these labels setted up like this:

Java ---------Progress bar-----------

C# ---------Progress bar-----------

This is my current code:

```
<div class="container">
            <p>
                C#
            </p>
            <div class="progress" id="prog1">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
                <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple add `progress-label` class to your `paragraph tag` with `float` and `margin`

```css
.progress-label {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p class="progress-label">
    C#
  </p>
  <div class="progress" id="prog1">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @VithorEscames why it doesn't work? Can you explain more? Also here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/teleginzhenya/s146sv1x/). Also here is [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/J8KH7)

Comment: @VithorEscames btw, did you add CSS?

Comment: The label still stays above the progress bar :/

Comment: @VithorEscames Сheck screens and send yours :)

Comment: Literally in any screen size is occurring that, the div "progress-bar" is occupying much space, causing this!

Comment: @VithorEscames is it works [now here](https://jsfiddle.net/teleginzhenya/76391ew6/)?

Comment: Still doesn't, there's a way to send you my site? It is hosted! I am not able to chat with you because my reputation is low..

Comment: you can send it telegin.zhenya@gmail.com :) i will check!

Comment: Made it! You can check it out!

Comment: @VithorEscames check your mail and feel free to ask any questions :)