# Having multiple progress bars in Bootstrap with left label pushing to the right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to have multiple progress bars using Bootstrap 4 with labels or at least text on its outer left. So far this works, but with multiple bars, it looks like an inverted stair.

[image]

What I currently have as code is the following:

```
    <div class="container">
      <p class="progress-label">
        C#
      </p>
      <div class="progress" id="prog1">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
          <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <p class="progress-label">
        C#
      </p>
      <div class="progress" id="prog1">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
          <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

with CSS

```
.progress-label {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

taken from [How to put a label side by a progress bar with bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43562533/how-to-put-a-label-side-by-a-progress-bar-with-bootstrap)
So far I am not sure what I can do to make it work properly, with both bars aligned.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rfo48n3d/):

Comment: from what I can see there is no issue with your code exept the double given id=prog1. could you provide more code a fiddle?

Comment: Added to the original post.

Comment: BTW, you can not have the same ID twice. Name the second "prog2".

Comment: @MarkusZeller, yes, I know, this is what I took from the linked post when looking for a solution. Normally I don't do it this way. But thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some points you should take care of:

- `container` class is not recommeded to use with inner elements, it is for the layout, **refer to this link:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/#containers
- ID should be unique, can't be used on multiple elements. Use classes for multi purpose.

my suggestion is to use those css styles to achieve what you need.

```
.container{
   margin: 10px;
}
.progress-label{
   padding: 0px 10px;
   float: left;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   top: -4px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This is the best of all solutions. Thank you.

Comment: @nucky pay attention to changes based on your page. you are welceome ^^

Answer (score 3):

Try to wrap each progress bar in a div with class called 'progressHolder'. Then in CSS just add 'overflow:hidden' since you have used 'float:left' in 'progress-label.'

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="progressHolder">
     <p class="progress-label">
       C#
     </p>
     <div class="progress" id="prog1">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
         <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="progressHolder">
     <p class="progress-label">
       C#
     </p>
     <div class="progress" id="prog2">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0"
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
         <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.progressHolder {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress-label {
  float: left;
  margin: -5px 15px 15px 0;
}
```

**Demo:**
https://codepen.io/Bibeva/pen/RwNMjNB

Answer (score 2):

Set the `.container` to `float: left` as well

I've added a calc to `margin-top` to center the text with the progress bar

```css
.container {
  float:left;
}

.progress {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.progress-label {
  float: left;
  margin-top: calc(1rem - 4px);
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p class="progress-label">C#</p>
  <div class="progress" id="prog1">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <p class="progress-label">C#</p>
  <div class="progress" id="prog2">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 40%">
      <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works so far. Just one more think as it appears right now: Is there a way to vertical align the label with the progress bar? https://jsfiddle.net/rfo48n3d/1/

Comment: @nucky if you want to vertical align label with the bar. remove float properties and use `text-align` as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<label>` instead of `<p>` in `progress-label`